# paste "( ," in dataframe r

Tags: r, report, paste

I have a data with four columns, I want to merge the last two columns and add "(," and ")" to those columns so that I can copy and paste the output to word.

```
                or      p     ll     ul
(Intercept)  0.007 <0.001  0.004  0.011
agecat35-54  1.266  0.017  1.043  1.537
agecat55-69  1.761 <0.001  1.432  2.166
agecat70-84  3.097 <0.001  2.467  3.888
agecat85+    4.229 <0.001  3.307  5.408
female_1     0.766 <0.001  0.684  0.857
```

Ideally, how can I make it looks like this:

```
                or      p    % 95 CI
(Intercept)  0.007 <0.001  (0.004, 0.011)
agecat35-54  1.266  0.017  (1.043, 1.537)
agecat55-69  1.761 <0.001  (1.432, 2.166)
agecat70-84  3.097 <0.001  (2.467, 3.888)
agecat85+    4.229 <0.001  (3.307, 5.408)
female_1     0.766 <0.001  (0.684, 0.857)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `paste0("(",dat$ll,",",dat$ul,")")`

Comment: @Onyambu Sorry, guess I answered at the same time.

Comment: no big deal ,. yours is an answer. mine is a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's call your dataframe df.

```
df$percent95CI <- paste0('(',df$ll,', ',df$ul,')')
```

The above expression would give you the desired column you like.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

data = read.table(header = T,text = 'or      p     ll     ul
(Intercept)  0.007 <0.001  0.004  0.011
agecat35-54  1.266  0.017  1.043  1.537
agecat55-69  1.761 <0.001  1.432  2.166
agecat70-84  3.097 <0.001  2.467  3.888
agecat85+    4.229 <0.001  3.307  5.408
female_1     0.766 <0.001  0.684  0.857')

# note the back ticks around the new column
# this allows the name to be created with arbitrary characters
summary <- 
  data %>%
  mutate(`% 95 CI` = paste0('(', ll, ', ', ul, ')')) %>%
  select(-ll, -ul)

rownames(summary) = rownames(data)
summary
#or      p        % 95 CI
#(Intercept) 0.007 <0.001 (0.004, 0.011)
#agecat35-54 1.266  0.017 (1.043, 1.537)
#agecat55-69 1.761 <0.001 (1.432, 2.166)
#agecat70-84 3.097 <0.001 (2.467, 3.888)
#agecat85+   4.229 <0.001 (3.307, 5.408)
#female_1    0.766 <0.001 (0.684, 0.857)
```